Получение прав доступа в Linux без использования битовой маски
Существует каталог /tmp/somefolder с правами drwxr-xr--,
а также файл /tmp/somefolder/file с правами -rw-r--r--.
Отсутствует информация о каталоге, в котором находится пользователь.
Пользователь не владеет директорией /tmp/somefolder и не входит в группу, владеющую этой директорией, аналогично он не владеет файлом /tmp/somefolder/file и не входит в группу, владеющую им.
Необходимо составить команду изменения прав доступа для каталога /tmp/somefolder/file без использования битовой маски для просмотра содержимого файла.Пользователь входит в sudoers.
Запрещено менять пользователя владельца и группу владельца.
Я составил команду sudo chmod o+x /tmp/somefolder.
На мой взгляд,направление правильное,но данная реализация не работает.

В смысле, после sudo права у /tmp/somefolder не меняются? А диагностика какая?

@avp
UPD:я посмотрел внимательно,да ,все работает.Вопрос решен.
Благодарю за участие!

В данном случае все-таки можно использовать команду sudo chmod o+x /tmp/somefolder, поскольку комбинация o+x означает, что мы можем получать доступ к атрибутам каталога и файла ,находящегося в нем,а также содержимому этих файлов (если файлы дают доступ).
Также обращу внимание на то,что к каталогу /tmp/ имеют доступ все пользователи системы.
Флаг o означает группу "others".
Флаг +x "execute" означает добавление права на исполнение каталога и файла,находящегося в нем.
